# How do I trigger an @keyframe animation on scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an @keyframe animation that rotates a circle on its x axis from 0  to 90 and then from 90 back to 0  degrees again. My goal is: when the user scrolls down the page, the rotation of the circle will simultaneously increase incrementally with the pace of the user’s scrolling until the scroll count reaches 160 down the page where the rotation of the circle will peak at 90 degrees. As the user continues to scroll down past 160, I want the circle to incrementally rotate back to 0 degrees once the user reaches 280 down the page.

So far I have tried putting the @keyframes into a class called Animation and then using classList.add in the JavaScript to call that class  but this did not work.

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.
P.S. I would like to use only JavaScript no jQuery.

```js
function Ani(){
  Ani.classList.add('Animation');  
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
section{

  height: 100vh;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.one{
  background-color: rgb(105, 170, 254);
}
#divItem {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;

  position: relative;
}

.triangle, .circle, .rectangle {
  position: absolute;


}


.circle {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
    animation: moving;
    animation-duration: 2s;
  }

  





.Animation{
@keyframes moving {
  0%{
    transform:rotateX(0deg);
    transform-origin: 30% 50%;
  }
  50%{
    transform:rotateX(90deg);
    transform-origin: 30% 50%;
  }
  100%{
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
}
}


.two{
  background-color: brown;
}
.three{
  background-color: bisque;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Scroll-Trigger</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <section class="one">

<div id="divItem">
   
    <img src="triangle.svg" class="triangle" width="150px" />
    <div class="Animation">
    <img src="circle.svg" class = "circle" width="150px"/>
  </div>
    <img src="rectangle.svg" class="rectangle" width="150px"/> 
</div>

</section>  
<section class="two">
   
</section>

<section class="three">
  
</section>
<script src="index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note that you don't put keyframes inside CSS class declarations, they're their own thing. Take it out of your `.Animation` rule (and probably lowercase that, it's just a CSS class) and instead then activate it in that class by giving it the `animation` rule with the keyframes name and animation properties (or separates it out into all the various individual `animation-*` rules).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind accomplishing your goal without keyframes, which IMO is a really challenging way to do it, I would recommend just setting the rotation of your element to match the scrollY of the page.

```
<div class="page">
  <div id="spinner"></div>
</div>
<script>
const handle = document.getElementById('spinner');
addEventListener('scroll', matchSpin);
function matchSpin () {
  let calc;
  if (scrollY < 160) {
    calc = scrollY  / (160 / 90)
  } else {
    calc = 90 - ((scrollY - 160) / (160 / 90))
  }
    handle.style.transform = `rotate(${calc}deg`;
}
</script>
```

```
.page {
  height: calc(320px + 100vh);
}

#spinner {
  position: fixed;
  left: calc(50vw - 35px);
  top: calc(50vh - 35px);
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  background: red;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
```

I'd put it in a code snippet, but I don't know how.
https://jsfiddle.net/27au5pzr/

Comment: Thank you for the code, it works! However do you know how to orientate the motion of the square (spinner) so that it rotates on the x axis toward the user like a pet door flapping up when Max (my dog) comes through?

Comment: You may have to fiddle with it a bit to get the perspective just right and maybe add a matching downward translation to anchor the top, but changing handle.style.transform = `rotate(${calc}deg`; -> handle.style.transform = `rotate3d(1, 0, 0, ${calc}deg`; will rotate it on the x axis.

Comment: When you say "add a matching downward translation to anchor the top" what do you mean, are you suggesting I change values of top: calc(50vh - 35px);  in the css? When I added handle.style.transform = rotate3d(1, 0, 0, ${calc}deg; in the JS the square did not move.

Comment: If you want it to look like a pet door, to me it would make sense to have it look like its hinged at the top rather than the center. Turns out trying to translate it downward is probably not the best way to do it. I'd imagine there's some fancy shenanigans you could do to make it work, but it seemed easier to just double its height and cover the top half with a linear gradient. I assume the reason it didn't move for you is because it was a string literal that stackoverflow marked up (the grey portions should be surrounded with `), which was my bad. https://jsfiddle.net/yhw5a6rb/

Comment: No worries, I really appreciate your help! And your code worked this time! Thank you.